# Unity Player Movement Y Axis(Something like Swing Copters)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Player moves on Y AXIS , but sometimes it doesnt go up but stucks in one place, Script is like in swing copters , when you touch it rotates to another side but its on X Axis , i took and made it on Y axis , but it doesnt work properly , player sometimes doesnt turn around and go up or back Please help out , sorry for bad english

```
void MovePlayerOnYAxis()
    {

        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {


            moveL = !moveL;

            if (moveL)
            {

                transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, -1, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            }

            huongbay = transform.localScale.x;
        }
        transform.root.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * huongbay * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Pre-Fix From @PompeyPaul But Player still doesnt go Down , it now goes only up.

```
void MovePlayerOnYAxis()
    {

        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {

            WasTouched = !WasTouched;


            if (WasTouched)
            {
                if (Input.touchCount == 0)
                {
                    WasTouched = false;

                    transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Input.touchCount > 0)
                {
                    WasTouched = true;
                    transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,-1, 1);
                }

            }
            huongbay = transform.localScale.y;

        }
        transform.root.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * huongbay * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following options:

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * huongbay * Time.deltaTime)
```

or

```
transform.root.position = transform.position + (Vector3.up * speed * huongbay * Time.deltaTime)
```

or

```
transform.position = transform.position + (Vector3.up * speed * huongbay * Time.deltaTime)
```